# Синтаксис meta-тэгов HTML

Tags: html, meta

Не могу понять, как верно, и имеет ли это значение

```
<!-- 1 --> <meta name="кeywords" content="........." /> 
<!-- 2 --> <meta name="кeywords" content="........."/> 
<!-- 3 --> <meta name="кeywords" content=".........">
```

Какой из вариантов правильный и почему?

Comment: Вам принципиально оформлять неправильно?) В подсвеченном коде разница прозрачно видна

Comment: ничего не понял)

Comment: так лучше воспринимается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, теоретически - браузеры едят все. НО: синтаксически (xhtml strict) верны 1 и 2, причем только 1 будет работать везде (некоторые старые браузеры считают слэш частью имени тега).

Если привыкнуть все одинарные теги писать в виде

```
<tag />
```

, не будет проблем ни с версиями html (ибо валидно везде), ни с кроссбраузерностью, ни с xml (ибо не будет привычки оставлять открытые теги).